# Internal speaker not working in netbook

Tags: sound

### Heading

Hello guys,
I have a problem with my built in speaker on asus eeePC, i'm running xubuntu 15.04. When I unplug the headphones, the built-in speaker isn't working. I've checked in alsamixer, it's set to 100%.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Asus eeePC 1015PX netbook. It was working fine on 14.04, but no speaker sound on 16.04.

## Quick workaround :

- First, open a terminal (with ctrl-alt-T for example), then type `alsactl restore` : for some reason, this fixes the issue
- But the problem re-appears after a reboot. In order to keep it, you can execute this command on each reboot, but you'll loose any sound configuration you might have done. For example, the master sound is by default at 50%

## How to keep sound settings after a reboot :

First, run the same `alsactl restore` command-line, then set the sound configuration as you like (through alsamixer or the GUI). Then you need to store it, and make Ubuntu restore it on reboot :

- You can store the config in a local file, for example : `alsactl --file /home/username/.config/asound.state store` (replace "username" with yours)
- Then, in the "startup application" app, add a new startup program, with the following command-line : `alsactl --file /home/username/.config/asound.state restore`. Note that, for some reason, using ~ instead of /home/username does not work when adding a startup program

Source : [http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/after-ubuntu-15-10-dist-upgrade-sound-only-comes-through-onboard-speakers-doesn't-work-with-headphones-4175572818/](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/after-ubuntu-15-10-dist-upgrade-sound-only-comes-through-onboard-speakers-doesn%27t-work-with-headphones-4175572818/)